# Format date with a 3-char month name abbreviation using AWK

Tags: datetime, awk, formatting

I have a datetime format as shown in the example below, which I want to convert to `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss` with AWK. How can I do this?

Current format:

```
3Jun2020 9:33:24; HG3456
7Jun2020 15:25:10; CH4747
10Jun2020 8:49:18; EU4821
12Jun2020 7:13:57; PP3478
```

Desired output:

```
03-06-2020 09:33:24; HG3456
07-06-2020 15:25:10; CH4747
10-06-2020 08:49:18; EU4821
12-06-2020 07:13:57; PP3478
```

Comment: You should really consider changing your desired date format to `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of `DD-MM-YYYY` as the former is much easier to work with, e.g. you can sort and/or compare it directly as a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{
    split($1,t,/[ :]/)
    lgth    = length(t[1])
    dayNr   = substr(t[1],1,lgth - 7)
    mthAbbr = substr(t[1],lgth - 6,3)
    mthNr   = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",mthAbbr) + 2) / 3
    yrNr    = substr(t[1],lgth - 3)

    $1 = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%04d %02d:%02d:%02d", dayNr, mthNr, yrNr, t[2], t[3], t[4])
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
03-06-2020 09:33:24; HG3456
07-06-2020 15:25:10; CH4747
10-06-2020 08:49:18; EU4821
12-06-2020 07:13:57; PP3478
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MPOSIX -MDate::Parse -pe 's{^\S+\s+\S+(?=;)}{strftime("%d-%m-%Y %T", strptime($&))}e; s/^0//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
3Jun2020 9:33:24; HG3456
7Jun2020 15:25:10; CH4747
10Jun2020 8:49:18; EU4821
12Jun2020 7:13:57; PP3478
```

then

```
awk '{sub(/Jan/,"-01-",$1);sub(/Feb/,"-02-",$1);sub(/Mar/,"-03-",$1);sub(/Apr/,"-04-",$1);sub(/May/,"-05-",$1);sub(/Jun/,"-06-",$1);sub(/Jul/,"-07-",$1);sub(/Aug/,"-08-",$1);sub(/Sep/,"-09-",$1);sub(/Oct/,"-10-",$1);sub(/Nov/,"-11-",$1);sub(/Dec/,"-12-",$1);print}' file.txt
```

output

```
3-06-2020 9:33:24; HG3456
7-06-2020 15:25:10; CH4747
10-06-2020 8:49:18; EU4821
12-06-2020 7:13:57; PP3478
```

Explantion: replace `Jan` using `-01-`, `Feb` using `-02-`, `Mar` using `-03-` and so on, then `print`. Disclaimer: code might need adjusting if you use other locale.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

If `sed` is an option, you can `e`xecute the `date` command within the replacement.

```
$ sed "s/\([^;]*\)\(.*\)/\date -d '\1' '+%d-%m-%Y %T\2'/e" input_file
03-06-2020 09:33:24; HG3456
07-06-2020 15:25:10; CH4747
10-06-2020 08:49:18; EU4821
12-06-2020 07:13:57; PP3478
```